# Why can't the compiler resolve an overload of a std::function parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, std, overloading

Observe the following example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>

void Print_Wrapper(std::function<void(int)> function);
void Print(int param);

int main(){

  Print_Wrapper(Print);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Print_Wrapper(std::function<void(int)> function){
  int i = 5;
  function(i);
}
void Print(int param){
  std::cout << param << std::endl;
}
```

This works correctly, and prints `5`.

---

Now look at the same example with an overloaded function added:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>

void Print_Wrapper(std::function<void(int)> function);
void Print(int param);
void Print(float param);

int main(){

  Print_Wrapper(Print);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Print_Wrapper(std::function<void(int)> function){
  int i = 5;
  function(i);
}
void Print(int param){
  std::cout << param << std::endl;
}
void Print(float param){
  std::cout << param << std::endl;
}
```

This gives the following compiler error:

> main.cpp:11:22: error: cannot resolve overloaded function ‘Print’
>   based on conversion to type ‘std::function’
>   Print_Wrapper(Print);

Could some explain why the compiler can't resolve the overload?
`Print_Wrapper` only expects an int function-- the float function shouldn't even be considered.

---

Additionally, what should I do to fix this?

I recall problems like this occurring if a `typename` or something was left out, but then that would require me to make `Print_Wrapper` a template.
Does `Print_Wrapper` need to be a function template?

I guess I'm use to functionality similar to this, that just works.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>

void Print_Wrapper(std::vector<int> param);
void Print(std::vector<int> param);
void Print(std::vector<float> param);

int main(){

  std::vector<int> vi{1,2,3};
  std::vector<float> vf{1.0,2.0,3.0};

  Print(vi); //prints int
  Print(vf); //prints float

  Print_Wrapper(vi); //prints int (no overload issue)
  Print_Wrapper(vf); //compiler error (as expected)

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

void Print_Wrapper(std::vector<int> param){
  Print(param);
  return;
}
void Print(std::vector<int> param){
  std::cout << "int" << std::endl;
}
void Print(std::vector<float> param){
  std::cout << "float" << std::endl;
}
```

So I think the issue lies somewhere in the lookup rules of an actual C++ function, as this example only uses types.  Thoughts?

Comment: std::vector<int> cannot be converted to std::vector<float> but int can be implicitly converted to float

Comment: `static_cast<void(*)(int)>(&Print)`

Comment: @Sarang ok, well if I use completely different types that can't be implicitly converted, I think the problem still remains.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In C++11, `std::function`'s constructor can take any callable object, even when that is ill-formed and it cannot call the object. In C++14, overload resolution is fixed but both functions can be called with `int` so both are valid candidates.

You need to explicitely request the correct function:

```
Print_Wrapper(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(Print))
```

Comment: Are you saying my example would work for C++14?

Comment: This solution works.  Without the cast, it still didn't work in C++14.

Comment: Hmm, originally I though it should work in C++14 but after careful examination of [LWG 2132](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2132), the issue is present even in C++14 because both can be called with `int`.

Comment: There is no easy way to say "this conversion is a preferred user-defined conversion to some other conversion" as far as I can tell.  Maybe with an unused varargs pack?  Seems dirty.

Comment: It is possible to prefer non-converting functions by declaring overloaded version of `Print_Wrapper`:
`void Print_Wrapper(void(*func)(int)) { Print_Wrapper(std::function<void(int)>(func)); }`

Answer (score 3):

You can assign both functions to `std::function<void(int)>` as both can be called with an int.

To force selecting correct overload with int version: `Print_Wrapper(static_cast<void(*)(int)>(Print));`

Comment: Did my issue have to do with ints being implicitly converted to a float, or would this happen with any two types?